# A continuous field of C* algebra, $C(\mathbb T)\rtimes\mathbb Z_2$

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

Given a $C^*$-algebra,

$A=${$f:[0,1]\rightarrow M_2(\mathbb C)$ where $f(0),f(1) $ are  diagonal
}

which is isomorphic to $C(\mathbb T)\rtimes\mathbb Z_2$,

How can I determine its continuous field of $C^*$-algebras?

I know the center is given by

$Z(A)=${$f : f(e^{i\pi t})=f(e^{-i\pi t})$} where $t\in [0,1]$

The ideal in $Z(A)$ is given by {$f : f(e^{i\pi t})=f(e^{-i\pi t})$=0} where $t\in [0,1]$

But I don't know how to go further from here.

Thank you.

Comment: First, could you clarify what you mean by the "continuous field of C$^*$-algebras of a C$^*$-algebra? Second, if $f:[0,1]\to M_2(\mathbb C)$, then $f(e^{it\pi}$ makes no sense. Same with the ideals.

Comment: Strangely, this is the 4th question about the same $C^*$-algebra in the last 10 days, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247491/universal-properties-of-certain-crossed-products , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249741/primitive-ideal-space-of-cz2z2 , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250962/irreducible-representation-of-cd-infty

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned,
$$
(\spadesuit) \qquad
C(\Bbb{T}) \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{Z}_{2} \cong
\{
f \in C([0,1] \to {\text{M}_{2}}(\Bbb{C})) \mid
\text{$ f(0) $ and $ f(1) $ are diagonal}
\}.
$$
Hence, by the definition of a continuous field of $ C^{*} $-algebras, $ C(\Bbb{T}) \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{Z}_{2} $ is a continuous field of $ C^{*} $-algebras over the compact Hausdorff space $ [0,1] $ with the following structure:

- The fibers over $ 0 $ and $ 1 $ are the $ C^{*} $-subalgebra of $ {\text{M}_{2}}(\Bbb{C}) $ consisting of all diagonal matrices, which is isomorphic to $ \Bbb{C} \oplus \Bbb{C} $.
- The fibers over $ (0,1) $ are $ {\text{M}_{2}}(\Bbb{C}) $.
- The generating $ * $-subalgebra of cross-sections is simply the set on the right-hand side of the relation $ (\spadesuit) $.

This agrees with a $ 1976 $ result by Ru-Ying Lee, which states that a $ C^{*} $-algebra $ A $ is a continuous field over a locally compact Hausdorff space $ X $ if and only if there exists a continuous open map from the primitive-ideal space of $ A $, $ \text{Prim}(A) $, *onto* $ X $.

As $ (\Bbb{Z}_{2},\Bbb{T},\alpha) $ is a **second-countable transformation group**, certain results in the theory of transformation-group $ C^{*} $-algebras show that $ \text{Prim}(C(\Bbb{T}) \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{Z}_{2}) $ is homeomorphic to a closed and bounded interval of $ \Bbb{R} $.

Of course, any $ C^{*} $-algebra is a continuous field over a single point, but this is uninteresting.

Comment: It’s to be assumed that a continuous field of $ C^{*} $-algebras has no zero-fibers.